# How do we know that the canonical surjection $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ denote a commutative ring. Consider a polynomial $P(x) \in R[x]$ and a commutative $R$-algebra $S$. Suppose we're given $a \in R$ such that $P(a) = 0$. There's an $R$-algebra homomorphism $R[x]/P(x) \rightarrow S$ given by mapping $x$ to $a$. My question is:

> **General Question.** What assumptions do we need (e.g. on $S$) for this to be injective?

Here's an example of why we might care:

Let $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ denote the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ by the polynomial $x^2-2$.

Let $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ denote the smallest subring of $\mathbb{R}$ containing the unique $a \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the following conditions: $$a^2-2 = 0, \qquad a>0.$$

There's a surjection $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ given by mapping $x$ to $a$.

> **Specific Question.** How can we show that this map injective?

To be clear, the actual question I'd like answered is the general one, not the specific one.

Comment: You are using one notation to denote two things that you do not know are isomorphic. That's among the worst possible ideas for notation available in the whole universe.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, it's just the emphasize that the question naturally arises to justify a common abuse of notation. I do not think this is a bad idea, and your comment seems misguided.

Comment: It is a bad idea. A very bad one. The common abuse of notation which you are referring is justified in that one knows how to show what you do not know how to show.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, here we go. Mariano is up to his old tricks again...

Comment: If my old trick is recognizing terribly bad notation and suggesting it be replaced by something sensible, well, I am proud.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, that's not your trick. Your trick is to passively-aggressively embed low-key abuse into your comments that's subtle enough that someone who does not know the history will not see it, while structuring your statements in such a way that the actual claims being made and/or the arguments in support of those claims can only be guessed at, making it impossible to give a dignified response. The natural response is overt aggression, which you use as an excuse to delete people's comments, perpetuating the cycle. In other words, business as usual for Mariano.

Comment: I am not abusing anyone. I am simply telling you that your choice of notation is really, really bad. There is no need to turn this into drama: we all pick bad notations from time to time. Along with a change of notation, I suggest you try to take constructive criticism better.

Comment: And **please** if you are trying to make the point that I deleted comments ---yours or of anyone else's---- start a mera thread with the details and I **promise** I'll take the time to convince other mods to copy there whatever comment you are saying I deleted (I won't do it myself, so as yo avoid your possible fears of me copying partially whatever it is you say I deleted) I have twice already told you this, and you have never followed suit, but I emphatically encourage you to do it.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, it's an objective matter of fact that there's semantical content in your comments that are not of the form 'I disagree with this choice of notation.' Saying that my objections to your use of language and power is just 'drama' is yet another attempt at concealing the intentionally low-key aggression at work here and is wildly intellectually dishonest.

Comment: I did not say I did not agree with your choice of notation: I was rather quite clear in saying that your notation is simply bad. There is a difference.

Comment: As said, please start a meta thread on whatever it is that bothers you: you are well aware that here this is off topic.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, yes, I was trying to make you seem less aggressive. But apparently, you like to be seen as aggressive. Perhaps you think this is what a moderator should be. If so, I firmly disagree.

Comment: There was nothing aggressive in telling you that the notation you picked is bad. I will ignore any other comments, as I expect you start a meta thread where all this you write has a chance of being on topic.

Comment: I agree with Mariano. Even the question title is surprisingly confusing. It's normal to use the same notation for isomorphic objects, but only *after* you prove the isomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

Simply show that the quotient of the polynomial ring $\mathbb Z[x]$ by $x^2-2$ has the classes of $1$ and of $x$ as a basis as an abelian group — this follows immediately from the fact that the polynomial is monic. Then just check by hand what you want.